# Javascript object and scopes

Tags: javascript, class, scope

In the code below, I can't access `this.children` from `init()`. Why can't I access it? How can I change my code to be able to access it?

Important: `this.camera` has to be accessible from outside the object. `init()` has to be private.

Please try not to only give a solution, but more of an explanation. I want to understand what I do.

```
PROJECT.element = function () {

    this.children = [1,2,5,8];


    ///////////
    //PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

    //Initialisation of the object.
    var init = function () {

        this.children.push(9);
    }

    init();
};
```

To keep Andy happy:

```
PROJECT.element.prototype.constructor = PROJECT.element;
var thisAwesomeVariableWithGreatNameForAndy = new PROJECT.element();
```

(I am sure that there are question similar to this one already, and I did read a nice amount of them, but it's hard to use the search function on "scope" and "object", because there are -a lot- of question)

Comment: Hint: your question title is about JS objects, but your code doesn't contain one.

Comment: @Andy: Presumably `new PROJECT.element` is being called at some point, creating an object.

Comment: You're far more trusting than me @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: @Andy there we go :) Hope this helps you sleep tonight! ;) (but you had a fair point)

Comment: `this` in JavaScript is really not that difficult. It is **always** what is left of the dot at **CALLTIME**!. To the left of `init()` is nothing, so `this` is nothing *(or window, or the global object)*. Try `var init = (function() { ... }).bind(this);` or `init.call(this);`

Comment: @atornblad: *"It is always what is left of the dot at CALLTIME!"* No, not always, as your examples demonstrate.

Comment: Well, internally it is still *(semi-)* correct, since `.bind`, `.call`, and `.apply` create closures, where the actual calling of the function is not obvious. But yeah, my comment seems to contradict itself. :)